# Gitlab "Forbidden" error

Tags: gitlab, rack, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus, rackattack

I are running GitLab - Version:10.0.3 and encountered the Forbidden error and Gitlab is forbidding our own office IP. I have already added our office IP in the gitlab_rails`['rack_attack_git_basic_auth'] section in gitlab.rb` file and also restart gitlab `gitlab-ctl restart` but still no luck. Please help to resolve.

`GitLab information
Version: 10.0.3`

Thanks

Comment: Can we take a look at the logfiles? Try to add as much information as possible, it can be anything.

Comment: Is there a proxy between you and gitlab ?

Answer (score 0):

The whitelist you defined is only used for the 'Fail2Ban' part (basic auth brute-forcing) of the Rack attack gem.

For throttling there is no whitelist configurable via gitlab.rb at present.

You can tune the behaviour of the throttling part of Rack Attack in general via gitlab.rb  by adding below options (experiment with the values)

```
#gitlab_rails['rate_limit_requests_per_period'] = 10
#gitlab_rails['rate_limit_period'] = 60
```

Don't forget to do a gitlab-ctl reconfigure (maybe you did, but you did not mention it explicitly)